# Set tooltip for a disabled button

Tags: angularjs

Please view my example in plunkr code on http://plnkr.co/edit/9dyBVZh67sxmIqUQB50S?p=preview

I have 4 buttons in which two buttons are disabled due to a condition.

I want to be able to display a tooltip over the two buttons that are disabled that would say "Test itemName2 is not available" for the first disabled button and "Test itemName4 is not available" for the second disabled button and no tooltip over the other two that are enabled.

Would this be possible? I have been toying around with ng-attr-title as seen in the example but is stuck on finding the solution to what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

html:

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller=ItemsController>
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <button ng-disabled="isDisabled(item.name)" ng-attr-title="{{item.name}}" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="select(item)" ng-repeat="item in itemDetails">{{item.name}}</button>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Script.js

```
var myItemsApp = angular.module('myItemsApp', []);

myItemsApp.factory('itemsFactory', ['$http', function($http){
  var itemsFactory ={
    itemDetails: function() {
      return $http(
      {
        url: "mockItems.json",
        method: "GET",
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
        });
      }
    };
    return itemsFactory;

}]);


myItemsApp.controller('ItemsController', ['$scope', 'itemsFactory', function($scope, itemsFactory){
  var promise = itemsFactory.itemDetails();

    promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.itemDetails = data;
        //console.log(data);
    });
    $scope.select = function(item) {
      $scope.selected = item;
    }
    $scope.selected = {};


    $scope.isDisabled = function(name){

      if(name == "Test itemName 2" || name == "Test itemName 4")
      {
        return true;
      }

    }



}]);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use:

```
        <div class="tooltip-wrapper" ng-repeat="item in itemDetails" title="{{item.name + (isDisabled(item.name)?' is not available' : '')}}">
          <button ng-disabled="isDisabled(item.name)" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="select(item)">{{item.name}}</button>
        </div>
```

Link demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hh1kH7HLatrQj76gFQ2E?p=preview

Comment: Sorry the question was  to be able to display a tooltip over the two buttons that are disabled that would say "Test itemName2 is not available" for the first disabled button and "Test itemName4 is not available" for the second disabled button and no tooltip over the other two that are enabled.

Comment: basicly I want different tooltips for disabled and enabled buttons

Comment: This doesn't achieve quite what you asked for.  The enabled buttons will have a tooltip of `item.name` (e.g. "Test itemName1"). You asked for no tooltip.

Comment: Yes, it is not completely right. I just show him the solution to achieve different tooltips for disabled and enabled buttons.

Comment: Should be `title="{{isDisabled(item.name) ? item.name + ' is not available' : ''}}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<button ng-disabled="isDisabled(item.name)" 
        ng-attr-title="{{ tooltipText(item) }}" 
        ng-repeat="item in itemDetails">{{item.name}}</button>
```

And then in your controller

```
$scope.tooltipText = function(item) {
  return $scope.isDisabled(item.name) ? item.name + ' is not available' : '';
};
```

Comment: Looks like at least Chrome is now firing mouse events for disabled buttons so this works when the button is enabled or disabled.  At some point in the recent past this did not work.

Comment: This worked for me since I am disabling a field on basis of a separate variable. Simple solution since chrome fire mouse event as @ammills01 mentioned..

Comment: If I am just add ng-attr-title inside button. It doesn't show any tooltip. Anything I have to modify?