# Nebular Angular Tooltip on disabled button is not working

Tags: angular, tooltip, nebular

Nebular Tooltip on disabled button is not working. Need to show tool tip on the disabled button.

Comment: Hi @UmeshPawar - normally would suggest a good question has a question that outlines what you've tried and stumbled with - although you have been lucky to get an answer

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48277910/11719787) for angular material applies to nebular too.

> This doesn't work because it is triggered by mouseenter event which
> doesn't get fired by most browsers for disabled elements. A workaround
> is to add <s>matTooltip</s> nbTooltip to a parent element:

So here is the solution, wrap it in a div and also make sure to change `div`'s display to `inline-block`

```html
<div nbTooltip="Tooltip is displayed on disabled button too">
  <button disabled>Hover to see tooltip</button>
</div>
```