# Angular display tooltip when button is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, angular-material

```
 <button
  [disabled]="(!dataConceptSummmaryFlag || dataConceptSummmaryFlag === false) && (!selectedLOBFlag || selectedLOBFlag === false) && (!adsListFlag || adsListFlag === false)"
  class="lmn-btn lmn-btn-primary"
  aria-label="Update"
  (click)="updateSelectedScopes()"
  [mtTooltip]="disabledContent"
 >
  Update
 </button>

   <ng-container *ngIf="(!dataConceptSummmaryFlag || dataConceptSummmaryFlag === false) && (!selectedLOBFlag || selectedLOBFlag === false) && (!adsListFlag || adsListFlag === false)">
       <ng-template #disabledContent>No New Scopes Values Selected</ng-template>
   </ng-container>
```

How can I display tooltip text on hover if button is disabled with the condition, also on I see red close icon when I hover over it. This is what i tried but it didn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material - How to add a tooltip to a disabled button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277909/angular-material-how-to-add-a-tooltip-to-a-disabled-button)

Comment: Disabled buttons don't receive any mouse events, that's why the tooltip is not showing when hovering the button. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled. See the linked question for approaches on how to fix it.

Comment: @NilsKähler Yes found the solution, added to parent element, working now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the files that overrides the Material styles:

```
// this workaround allows for the tooltips to appear on disabled buttons (since mouse events aren't fired for them)
button:disabled.mat-mdc-tooltip-trigger {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
  // remove the ripple effect on hover
  > span:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

It will show the tooltip without the ripple background on hover.